# having problems to uninstall

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i'm trying to :

```
sudo apt-get remove ros
```

i got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package ros
```

what am i missing here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46557/having-problems-to-uninstall/) by [nir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3001/nir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Google could have helped. Have a look at [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/45218/uninstall-ros/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1